# Use of COM Class in PHP

Tags: php, excel, com

I am  using  following code to access excel file  in php.

```
        $excel = new COM("Excel.application",,) or die ("ERROR: Unable to instantaniate   COM!\r\n");

// DATA RETRIEVAL
$Workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Open($file) or die("ERROR: Unable to open " . $file . "!\r\n");
$Worksheet = $Workbook->Worksheets($sheet);
$Worksheet->Activate;
```

The above code working on local machine but when I try to execute this code on any web server then It's not  working. Can Someone help me Where is the problem in this code.

Comment: COM is Windows specific. Are your web servers running Windows?

Comment: And if your web server is Windows, do you have Excel installed on it?

Comment: the web server process might not have permission to load the excel binary .

Answer (score 4):

I advice you to use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) instead of COM.

COM is really slow and work only on windows, plus you have to install office on a server which is a waste of a license.

Comment: I don't think that microsoft would call that a waste of a license ;)

Comment: How should I use PHPExcel, I  want  store excelsheet data in php array.

Comment: MS might not call it a waste of a license, but it is a waste to your business if you buy a license for your *nix server

Comment: @Mukesh - Try reading some of the PHPExcel documentation about reading workbooks first, and look at some of the examples in the download... __then__ ask if you have any specific questions

Answer (score 0):

You need Excel to be installed on your servers + the php process needs the correct permissions to be able to access the COM application.

We've had lot's of trouble with Office Interop in the past and I advise against it. If anything happens to your process the Excel instances are kept open on the server and these instances take up a lot of RAM.

You are better off using libraries that leverage the OpenXML specification, such as Spreadsheetlight:

http://spreadsheetlight.com/

You can use it from PHP, there is an example here:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/importing-excel-data-php-openxml-and-spreadsheetlight-drupal-example